# JavaScript NOT operator on Boolean

Tags: javascript, css, animation

So I finally got a piece of code to work, but I'm having trouble understanding why it works. My CSS basically has a 
sprite sheet that animates a box morphing into a circle.

The `animation-play-state : paused;` is a rule in my CSS that keeps the sprite from starting its animation till the key is pressed as you will see in the JavaScript code.

My question is why does the if execute the code block when `keycheck` is `false`. From my knowledge of how the `!` operator works, isn't the code only suppose to execute when the `keycheck` is "NOT" false ? Its initial value is `false` so why does it run ?

The code is suppose to stop the event from executing repeatedly when a key is held down.

```
keycheck = false;

window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKey_DN, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", checkKey_UP, false);

function checkKey_DN(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == "83" && !keycheck){
        keycheck = true;
        $("boxMorph").style.animationPlayState = "running";
        $("boxMorph").style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
        $("boxMorph").style.visibility = "visible";
        $("boxMorph").classList.remove ("boxes");
        $("boxMorph").offsetWidth = $("boxMorph").offsetWidth;
        $("boxMorph").classList.add ("boxes");      

      }
  }

function checkKey_UP(e){
    if(e.keyCode == "83"){
        keycheck = false;
        $("boxes").style.visibility = "hidden";
      }
  }
```

This piece of code helps re-animate the css sprites.

```
$("boxMorph").classList.remove ("boxes");
$("boxMorph").offsetWidth = $("boxMorph").offsetWidth;
$("boxMorph").classList.add ("boxes");
```

Comment: If the initial value is `false`, then `!false === true` ... the if condition is an AND condition using `&&`, so it evaluates to true if both parts are evaluated to true. And `!false` evaluates to true, of course

Comment: I think you wanted to use `if(keycheck != false)` which is equivalent to `if(keycheck)` and is the exact opposite of `if(!keycheck)`

Comment: Ahhh I see.... I misunderstood it wrong this whole time. Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misunderstood NOT - it returns the inverse of the value:

```
if(false) { /* this block will not be executed */ }

if(!false) { /* this block will be executed */ }
```

This is because `!false` evaluates as `true`, which is equivalent to:

```
if(true) { /* this block will be executed */ }
```

The check `if(!keycheck)` will succeed *only* when the value of keycheck is falsy, e.g. `keycheck = false`.

Comment: This whole time I've been misunderstanding it wrong... Thanks a lot for the explanation!

Comment: Happy to help :¬)  Please accept my answer if it is correct.

Comment: I had to wait a while to accept the answer, but there you go. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

`!` Operator is negation operator and not the `!=` to operator.

Comment: It seems that I've got them mixed up. Thanks for clearing that up!